# redis rdb file permission denied in AWS ECS

Tags: docker-compose, redis, amazon-ecs

i have this redis service in my docker compose file

```
 redis:
container_name: redis
image: redis:${VERSION_REDIS}
ports:
  - "6379:6379"
networks:
  - backend
```

if i run docker-compose locally, than the redis db is working as intended.

```
1:M 12 Jun 2022 14:47:51.212 * Running mode=standalone, port=6379.
1:M 12 Jun 2022 14:47:51.213 # Server initialized
1:M 12 Jun 2022 14:47:51.215 * Loading RDB produced by version 6.2.5
1:M 12 Jun 2022 14:47:51.216 * RDB age 728 seconds
1:M 12 Jun 2022 14:47:51.219 * RDB memory usage when created 0.79 Mb
1:M 12 Jun 2022 14:47:51.219 * DB loaded from disk: 0.004 seconds
1:M 12 Jun 2022 14:47:51.220 * Ready to accept connections
```

The version used is 6.2.5-buster. If i try to use docker-compose to my AWS ECS cluster, every service starts normal but the redis task has the following protocol output:

```
12.6.2022, 16:32:34 1:M 12 Jun 2022 14:32:34.734 # Failed opening the RDB file crontab (in server root dir /etc) for saving: Permission denied  
12.6.2022, 16:32:34 1:M 12 Jun 2022 14:32:34.164 # Failed opening the RDB file zzh (in server root dir /etc) for saving: Permission denied  
12.6.2022, 16:32:32 1:M 12 Jun 2022 14:32:32.836 # Failed opening the RDB file root (in server root dir /etc) for saving: Permission denied 
12.6.2022, 16:32:32 1:M 12 Jun 2022 14:32:32.646 # Failed opening the RDB file root (in server root dir /etc) for saving: Permission denied 
12.6.2022, 16:32:32 1:M 12 Jun 2022 14:32:32.267 # Failed opening the RDB file root (in server root dir /etc) for saving: Permission denied 
12.6.2022, 16:32:30 1:M 12 Jun 2022 14:32:30.939 # Failed opening the RDB file backup.db (in server root dir /etc) for saving: Permission denied
12.6.2022, 16:40:47 1:M 12 Jun 2022 14:40:47.168 # Background saving error
```

i tried to search for solutions, but i am just starting out with container services on AWS. How can i configure my docker-compose file or how to change the permissions inside aws to make redis work? Are there other ways? Thank you. The cluster is running on fargate.

Comment: have you found a solution for this? Thx

Comment: unfortunately the only solution for me was to switch from fargate to a normal EC2 Instance. There redis was working as intended. I sadly have no solution to run a redis-container on an AWS-Fargate instance.